# attribute name for serial or parallel

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails model that needs an attribute that can have a value of either serial or parallel, what would be the correct name for this attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the name I'm looking for is seriality. Thanks for the responses though :)

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

- `communication`
- `communication_stream`
- `communication_type`
- `stream`
- `stream_type`

Answer (score 1):

This needs more context. Many things can fall into either serial or parallel descriptions. Ports, and circuits come to mind.

If this is the case, I'd name the attribute type, prefixed with a generic description of the the object in question.

Example,  If it the model dealt with an electronic device that connected on either the serial or a parallel port, I'd name it port_type.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking, but I was hoping there was a term to refer to the type, like cardinality would refer to the direction an object is facing.

Comment: The "type" attribute is reserved and can't be used.

Comment: yeah, i know that, type is too generic anyway. I was looking for something that encapsulates the idea. right now i'm just calling the attribute serial, and it's boolean. I think i'm actually going to go with seriality.